# How can I get Windows 10 to stop asking me to update my file associations?

Tags: windows-10

I just upgraded from Windows 7 to Windows 10, and now, every time I open a file type I haven't yet opened in Windows 10, I get this dialog:

[image: How do you want to open this file?]

I understand that I can check the "Always use this app to open these files" box to get Windows to shut up about *that particular file type*, but with literally thousands of file types on my system and hundreds of programs governing them, I'll be doing this for years and years to come. How can I get Windows 10 to shut up and just let me keep using my existing file associations?

Comment: So u dont want the open with dialog with suggested apps everytime?or u just need to associate default files with respective tool

Comment: I don't want the dialog.

Comment: "literally thousands of file types on my system" - unlikely. I have less than 500 registered file types on a 5 year old PC.

Answer (score 3):

There seems to be the [solution](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/4171-new-app-installed-notification-enable-disable-windows-10-a.html) to similar to yours issue. You should be able to disable this functionality by following the instruction provided in the link.
This is only applicable if are on *Pro*, *Enterprise* or *Education* editions.

1. Open Group Policy by typing `gpedit.msc` in `Run`
2. Expand the **Computer Configuration -> Administrative Templates -> Windows Components** and open **File Explorer**
3. In **File Explorer** choose **Do not show the 'new application installed' notification.**
4. That's the part where it gets a bit weird:

   - To **Enable** the notifications choose either **Not configured** or **Disabled**
   - To **Disable** the notifications choose **Enabled**

Check out the snapshots below.
[image: Group policy window]
[image: Configuration window]
Hope this helps.

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change. It's also an answer to a different problem, so it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: For some reason my win 10 install seemed to permenantly think it had  a new jpg viewer installed, so just looped popping up the choice dialog.  This was the only way I found to fix it

Answer (score 0):

Open the Windows 10 `Control Panel`, then click `Programs`, then `Default Programs`. The first two entries on this list are what you’re interested in.

If you’d like to set a single program as the default for all the types of files it’s capable of opening, click `set your default programs`. This screen opens a list of your installed programs in the column on the left. Click a program in the left column, then click `set this program as default` to apply all of the **file type associations** that the program includes.

Another option, you may see on the screenshot you attached, is to use the checkbox at the bottom of the dialog `Always use this app to open ...`. It will ask you once, and will remember you setting.